# Doubt about Covariance

Tags: variance, covariance

The covariance measures the tendency of 2 random variables (for example) to have the same sign. Suppose that we choose 2 random variables that tend to have discordant sign, but the few times they are concordant the product (X1-X1_avg)(X2-X2_avg) is very high. So the covariance is a large value, even if the two variables have a tendency to be discordant in sign. This is in contrast with the first sentence. Where am i wrong ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your initial sentence is incorrect.  See [some of our threads about covariance.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=covariance%20-pca)

Comment: So, the covariance is NOT a measure of the probability that 2 random variables are concordant (or discordant) in sign. To me it seems a very vague and inaccurate measure :S

Answer (score 0):

As @whuber noted in a comment, the first sentence is incorrect. If that sentence were correct then any two variables that were always the same sign (either positive or negative) would have infinite covariance and any that always had opposite sign would have 0 covariance.

Nor is your comment in reply to his correct. The covariance is precisely defined and is neither vague nor inaccurate. It's true that the correlation is often more interpretable, but that is simply a scaled version of covariance.

A measure of how concordant in sign two variables were *might* be a little bit useful only for variables that had means of 0. Even then, though, I think other measures would be better.